# How to remove vuetify autocomplete component default icon

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component, vuetify.js

Vuetify autocomplete by default have custom "up" and "down" arrow icons:

[image: Down arrow by default]
[image: Up arrow when input active]

How can be changed this icon to search icon in other events (active or inactive) and get this view:

[image: Text field example search bar]

This example created using `v-text-field`:

**Code:**

```
<v-text-field
  flat
  solo
  hide-details
  append-icon="search"
  label="Search..."
  color="#000000"
></v-text-field>
```

I tired append icon to vuetify autocomplete component but can't remove default up and down rows.

**Code:**

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="select"
  :append-outer-icon="search ? 'search' : 'search'"
  label="Search..."
  type="text"
  :loading="loading"
  :items="items"
  :search-input.sync="search"
  cache-items
  class=""
  flat
  hide-no-data
  hide-details
  @click:append-outer="startSearch"
></v-autocomplete>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Generaly how I can change arrow icons to search icon and do it as clickable for search?

Comment: Which version of vuetify framework are you using?

Comment: Version `0.5.5`  @skribe

Comment: Oh wow.  Later versions of the framework > 1.0 I believe support changing the icon by passing a prop.   If changing framework version is not an option (a lot of things have changed and will break)  then you can try  `Vue.prototype.$vuetify.icons = {  dropdown: 'search'};`   But I am not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: I use it with `nuxt.js` framework

Comment: Otherwise in the past to handle similar issues I extended the component to customize it how I wanted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `append-icon=""` and set it to blank

Here's the example.

If you want to append icon with callback function use `append-icon-cb="()"`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqXVWj?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: I need search icon inside search bar and do it clickable. It's available? @ßiansor Å. Ålmerol

Comment: @AndreasHunter Yes it is, I edited my example in codepen,  let me know.

Comment: append-icon-cb="()" is depreciated now. Use the v-on:click event like, @click:append="()"

Answer (score 0):

Try this `append-icon="mdi-magnify"`